# Need to add 5 "@" symbols. 4 in each corner and one in the middle

Tags: java

So the program makes the shape I need it to make. But I can't seem to figure out where in the code to make it print out the @.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int n = 9;
  for(int row = 0; row < n ; row++)
  {
     for(int col = 0; col < n ; col++)
     {
     if(row == 0 || col == 0 || row ==  n - 1 || col == n - 1) 
        System.out.print("*");
     else if(row + col == n - 1 || row == col)
        System.out.print("+");
     else
        System.out.print(" ");
     }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert a single `if` statement and an `else` to cover the four corners and the middle, like

```
int n = 9;
for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
        if ((row == 0 || row == n - 1) && (col == 0 || col == n - 1) 
                    || (row == col && col == n / 2))
            System.out.print("@");
        else if (row == 0 || col == 0 || row == n - 1 || col == n - 1)
            System.out.print("*");
        else if (row + col == n - 1 || row == col)
            System.out.print("+");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

That gives me

```
@*******@
*+     +*
* +   + *
*  + +  *
*   @   *
*  + +  *
* +   + *
*+     +*
@*******@
```

Comment: @Richard Edit your question to include the desired output. Especially if it differs from what I have posted. Which should be exactly the same as you get. I didn't do anything fancy, just added the five conditions you specified.